# Add elements to fifo queue

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm trying to add int variables to this fifo. 
[fifo.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dtrace/dtrace-48/tools/ctfconvert/fifo.c)

But I only see the same var (this is the last var)

```
fifo_t *ff = fifo_new();


for (int i =0; i<4; i++) {
    int *k = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *k = rand();
    printf("%d %p!\n", *k, k);
    fifo_add(ff, k);
    free(k);
}

fifo_iter(ff, my_callback, NULL);
```

If I create int var in stack and add to fifo like this

```
    int x =0;
fifo_add(ff, (void *)x);
x = 2;
fifo_add(ff, (void *)x);
x = 3;
fifo_add(ff, (void *)x);
```

It is work fine, but I have warning - "cast to pointer from integer of different size"

What I do wrong? Best regards.

**EDIT**: 
I found function in fifo.c for destroying all elements of fifo queue. For my example, you need to call fifo_free(of, NULL); If you will add your custom struct to the queue, you need to will write some function for destroying you struct and put it in second parametr of fifo_free.

ty for @JonathanLeffler and other commentators

Comment: The two are not equivalent. `fifo_add(ff, (void *)x);` that adds an int value. `fifo_add(ff, k);` that adds a pointer to the int value. So are you really trying to store an int or a pointer to an int?

Comment: One thing you're doing wrong is calling `free()` in the loop.  Look at the code in `fifo.c`; it copies the pointer into the structure (it can't copy the data because it isn't told how big the data is).  So, you keep abusing the memory by allocating it, copying the pointer to it into the FIFO, then freeing it.  You probably get the same memory each time you allocate, so each new entry tramples over the previous one.  Move the `free()` to a separate loop — or a new callback function.

Comment: I trying to store pointer. i know that they are not equal:)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How do I know since a chunk of memory me start?  Ty for answers guys.

Comment: "I have warnings". It could be a good idea to share with us what warnings you get exactly.

Comment: @MichaelWalz there is "cast to pointer from integer of different size"

Comment: @garrydvaraza please edit your question and don't put complementary information in comments and please specify the line number.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  i delete free from loop and add this  k = k-4*sizeof(int); free(k);  in other loop :)  But I think it is bad solution.

Comment: You're right that the computation on `k` for freeing is bad.  That's why I mentioned a new callback function for use with `fifo_iter()`.  I didn't recheck the source, but you're probably passed a pointer to the data on each call of the callback, so you'd pass that to `free()`.   The you'd destroy the FIFOs with the appropriate function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I understand now. I have to write a new function for the destruction of fifo and free all the pointers are added in the loop. ty very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
fifo_add(ff, &x);
```

You need to pass a pointer to `data`, rather than a casted scalar type, because `fn_data` is declared to be a `void *`, and a `void *` is not guaranteed to hold all scalar types. As a result, it's **not possible** to add `int` variables to a fifo.

Also note that

```
int x =0;
fifo_add(ff, &x);
x = 2;
fifo_add(ff, &x);
x = 3;
fifo_add(ff, &x);
```

may not work as you expect. It's the address of `x` that is stored in the new node, not the value it contains. So you will end up getting 3 new nodes, whose `fn_data`s point to a common memory.